# Dimensionality reduction and dynamic weighing of large set of correlated features

Tags: time-series, prediction, dimensionality-reduction

I have a relatively large number of scalar-valued features (in the order of 1000), each given as an equidistant time series. These features are predictors of a target quantity (the features use different forecasting techniques, but for the present purpose can be considered black boxes).

The problems I want to tackle:

1. How do I find the combination (including weights) of the features that yields the best prediction of the target quantity? I'd categorize possible approaches in the following increasing order of complexity:

   (a) Linear combination with constant weights (regression problem: OLS, LASSO, ...?)

   (b) Linear combination with dynamically updated weights (perhaps based on recent prediction error; maybe something based on Kalman filter?)

   (c) Non-linear techniques (neural nets, ...)
2. As many of my features are quite correlated, I want to reduce the number of features that I'm using for my forecasting. How to find the smallest set of relevant features for a good prediction?

I've considered regression for (1a) (regressing my features onto the prediction target). I could use t-statistic of the coefficients or LASSO to judge the relevance of a predictor (although I've heard that LASSO is not a good approach for a very large number of predictors). Am I on the right track, or what should I look at?

This would give me constant weights. But as not all predictors work good throughout the whole prediction period, it's probably better to use dynamic weights and include the recent prediction error into the weighing scheme. Any pointers on suitable techniques for (1b) and (1c)?

I've thought of using PCA for (2), but this doesn't seem right intuitively, as it doesn't reduce the number of my predictors, just groups them differently into eigenvectors. I'm aware of feature-selection techniques such as forward selection or backward elimination. Would these the a good choice, or can I do something smarter given the structure of my problem?

Comment: Lag effects would be quite important. I have introduced that into feature selection  (dimensionality reduction) . If you wish you can post a small example of your data. contact me to let me know you have done this as my comment won't automatically trigger an advisory / response to me.

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm not permitted to share my data.

Do you have a reference regarding lag effects in feature selection? Without knowing specifics, could you give general advice on how to combine several forecasts obtained with different models and to increase the fidelity of the aggregate forecast, as well as weed out useless forecasts? My intuition is that an iterative procedure based on error correction (error being the a-posteriori forecasting error) could be an appropriate approach.

Comment: Are ensemble learning concepts such as boosting and bagging relevant in this context?

Comment: In selecting a good predictor one needs to consider lag effects of the predictor rather than just a contemporaneous relationship.